# Big-O and little-o properties of polynomial $3x^4+6x^3-15x^2+4$

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics

Which of the following statements are correct?

A. $3x^4+6x^3-15x^2+4 \in O(x^4)$ 
 B. $3x^4+6x^3-15x^2+4 \in o(x^4)$ 
 C. $3x^4+6x^3-15x^2+4 \in o(x^3)$ 
 D. $3x^4+6x^3-15x^2+4 \in O(x^5)$ 
 E. $3x^4+6x^3-15x^2+4 \in o(x^5)$

I have taken up through Calculus 3 and learned about Taylor series expansions. However, we didn't go over Big Oh and Little Oh notation. I have looked at other questions on StackExchange concerning this notation, but I'm not sure how to answer this question because it asks about a polynomial, not necessarily a series expansion.

Comment: if you knew coding https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/ gives a nice intro to it.

Comment: There's some ambiguity. Are we taking $x \to 0$, or $x \to \infty$?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122. Good point. Big-$O$ and Little-$o$ are also used when $x\to -\infty$ and when $x\to k$ for some finite $ k.$ Not stating which it is, is like writing $\lim f(x)$  without stating where $x$ is going.

Comment: Removed the references to Taylor series in the tags and title because they do not seem to be relevant to the question.

Comment: This was all the information provided for the question. So sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the degrees in the O-notation terms are all equal to or larger than the degree in their respective equation, it can safely be assumed that the author of the question was implying as $ x \rightarrow \infty $.

---

In the most basic terms, big-O says "grows no faster than". So, for $O(x^5)$, the largest degree of any polynomial that satisfies this notation will be $x^5$.

Little-o is to big-O what $>$ is to $\ge$. So, for $ o(x^5) $, the largest degree of any polynomial that satisfies this notation will be $x^4$, assuming we're using integral powers.

If dealing with

There is actually a different notation for each inequality sign:

- $O(x^5)$ implies degree $\le 5$.
- $o(x^5)$ implies degree $< 5$.
- $\Theta(x^5)$ implies degree $= 5$.
- $\Omega(x^5)$ implies degree $> 5$.
- $\omega(x^5)$ implies degree $\ge 5$.

If dealing with $ x \rightarrow 0 $, simply use these inequalities bottom to top. This is because as $ x \rightarrow 0 $, $ x^n \rightarrow 0 $, and the notations specifically talk about growth (i.e the original ones talk about decay, so it goes bottom to top).

**Correct equations:**

> A, D and E.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot more sense.